Locking a column in excel to not changing when pasting other values
I want to lock a column to be able to change it but keep the format as it is.

I did the normal thing like everyone said, Ctrl + A to take whole cells, unlocked them. I chose the 4th column since I want to keep it as a text. I clicked the whole d column, made it text and then went to protection and made it locked. Still the cells change. If you paste something from a different excel or anywhere it changes the format. I dont want that. I want to automatically take the text format.

I think you need the special paste options (right click -> special paste -> formulas or values, depending on what you need); apart from that, you tagged two different excel versions, which one are you using?

Locking a cell does nothing until you protect the sheet.

I look for the 2019 version,
I also protected the sheet but I cant paste anything if i protect it

If the goal is to prevent others from changing a format when they paste, it might be easier to use vba to reapply original formats than to prevent them from pasting new formats.

That is something that I did not think of. Thank you. I will do that.
